# Update Document with Array of subdocument with Mongoose called from an Angular component failed

Tags: angular, mongoose, mean-stack

In MEAN stack, I am trying to update a mongoose document from Angular but I don't have the expected result : only the document is updated but not the subdocument associated (the value is replaced by null)

I am using the following model in mongoose :

```
/* Mongoose file - thread.model.js */
var ThreadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true
  },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  messages: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message', required: true
  }],
  numberOfViews: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  numberOfAnswers: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  numberOfLikes: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  numberOfThanks: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  tags: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'
  }]
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt' } });
```

and this update query that I tested with Postman with successful results, maybe not the more optimized but it seems to work :

```
/* Express & Mongoose file - threads.route.js */
router.put('/:threadId', function(req, res, next) {
  Thread.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.threadId, { title: req.body.title },
    function(err, thread) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      Message.findByIdAndUpdate(thread.messages[0], { text: req.body.text }, 
        function(err, message) {
          if (err) return next(err);
      });
      res.json(thread);
  });
});
```

Now, in Angular I have a component supposed to update my threads when the user submits the reactive form with this code :

```
/* Angular file - threads-edit.component.ts */
onSubmit(): void {
    // Set the data model with its corresponding form model
    this.thread.title = this.threadForm.value.title;
    this.thread.messages[0].text = this.threadForm.value.text;

    this.threadService.updateThread(this.thread)
      .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
}
```

The submit method call the threadService with the update method which only call the API put for the threads:

```
 /* Angular file - thread.service.ts */
 updateThread(thread: Thread): Observable<any> {
   const id = thread._id;
   const url = `${this.threadsUrl}/${id}`;

   return this.http.put(url, thread, httpOptions).pipe(
     catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateThread'))
   );
 }
```

Below an example of execution before the update.

After a new thread POST :

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "comments": [],
            "_id": "5b25e52eeb7f580b59d6a431",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum",
            "createdAt": "2018-06-17T04:35:58.284Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-06-17T04:35:58.284Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "numberOfViews": 0,
    "numberOfAnswers": 0,
    "numberOfLikes": 0,
    "numberOfThanks": 0,
    "tags": [],
    "_id": "5b25e52deb7f580b59d6a430",
    "category": "5b25e520eb7f580b59d6a42e",
    "title": "Foo",
    "createdAt": "2018-06-17T04:35:57.738Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-06-17T04:35:58.747Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

And after the update PUT :

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "comments": [],
            "_id": "5b25e52eeb7f580b59d6a431",
            "text": null,
            "createdAt": "2018-06-17T04:35:58.284Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-06-17T04:40:20.351Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "numberOfViews": 0,
    "numberOfAnswers": 0,
    "numberOfLikes": 0,
    "numberOfThanks": 0,
    "tags": [],
    "_id": "5b25e52deb7f580b59d6a430",
    "category": "5b25e520eb7f580b59d6a42e",
    "title": "Bar",
    "createdAt": "2018-06-17T04:35:57.738Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-06-17T04:40:20.341Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

I hope I was clear enough in my explanation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I suppose you're passing the `thread` as the `requestBody`. `req.body.title` = `thread.title` but I don't think `req.body.text` = `thread.text` !? Hence it is `null`.

And your `after new thread POST` and `after the update PUT` `thread` does not have the same `_id`? Are those two supposed to be the same?

Comment: You are right, `req.body.text` = `this.thread.messages[0].text` because it is the first message of my thread I'd like to change. i changed it in my code and now it's working! Thanks a lot

Comment: You need use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator to update an array in mongodb